# Open source application for converting img to iso and vice versa for Windows 10

Tags: windows, open-source, iso, file-conversion

I want an open-source program that converts images with .img extension to .iso extension. The last thing I want to do is download a large 5gb .img and empty my mobile data and then end up unable use it for virtualbox as .iso
Please try to stick to open-source apps.

Comment: Welcome Sujay!  Your question was flagged by our community as needing details and clarity.  After reading your question a couple times, I understand what you are seeking, but perhaps you can edit your question to make it more clear.  Also, please make it clear if Windows 10 the operating system being used, or if it is the actual contents of the .img files you want to convert to .iso?

Comment: It is the contents of .img file that I want to convert to .iso and by windows I mean the operating system in which I want to perform this task